# How to disable 'stretching' for lists?

Tags: .net, winforms, reporting-services

I have a ReportViewer in a Windows Forms application (vb.net).

I have a report with a list in it, and the list will only be 1 or 2 deep. I don't want the surrounding report to render 'stretched' if the list has 2 items in it. Is there a property I can toggle to turn off stretching?

Cheers.

Comment: I started to write an answer, but then realized that you might be talking about something other than GUI.  Can you please clarify this in your question?  Perhaps it's my lack of knowledge about "reporting services" in .NET.

Comment: It's in the final rendering of the report - when there are 2 items, the surrounding container is stretched to accommodate the larger list size, and I don't want it to do that.

Comment: I added my answer since you are talking about GUI, but it would be most beneficial if you can narrow it down for us -- WinForms?  WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assume SQL Reporting Services or a ReportViewer control...

You should be able to set [CanGrow = false](http://pierrerebours.com/blog/canshrink-and-cangrow-behaviors) on the List item.

If this doesn't work, put the list inside a rectangle [and set CanGrow on the rectangle.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/597a129f-301b-422e-94b6-2c1e20bfb1d0)

Comment: It's part of the Field properties and seems to apply only to Fields... there isn't one for Rectangles or other surrounding containers?

Comment: So the person on the last link solved their problem by placing the list inside a "list data region"... what does that mean, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a WPF application here?  Is the issue that your container is auto-sizing to its content?  You can either set the exact height of the control, e.g.

```
<ListBox Height="80" />
```

or you can do what I prefer to do in my GUIs, which is to pick the critical visual element for presenting information, and make sure that autosizes to the window itself.  If you use a container like a `DockPanel`, the last child defined in XAML will automatically size itself to fill the remainder of the `Window`, or whatever other control it's contained by.

Comment: This is a Winforms application. The container is autosizing to accommodate the extra rows, and that's fine. But everything below it in the report is nudged down that extra row space.

Comment: I'm a WPF guy, so I will defer to those that know WinForms.